# Can't build JFXtras Labs 8.0 on Windows

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, jfxtras

When trying to build JFXtras Labs 8.0 on Windows, I get various error messages such as:

> Please set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to the directory that contains jre/lib/jfxrt.jar of JavaFX version 8.0.

or:

> Please set the environment variable JAVA_HOME
>   to the directory that contains jre/lib/jfxrt.jar
>   of JavaFX version 8.0.

How should I define the environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\"
set JAVAFX_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext"
```